# Interactive floor plan graph using Python Bokeh

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I am trying to create an interactive floor-plan using Python.
Is there a way to make polygons clickable and then bring them to front in Bokeh?

In the below example:

```
import json

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show

xs_dict = [
  [ { 'exterior': [1, 8, 8, 1], 'holes': [] } ],
  [ { 'exterior': [5, 8, 8, 5], 'holes': [] } ]
]

ys_dict = [
  [ { 'exterior': [2, 2, 10, 10], 'holes': [] } ],
  [ { 'exterior': [7, 7, 10, 10], 'holes': [] } ]
]


xs1 = [[[p['exterior'], *p['holes']] for p in mp] for mp in xs_dict]
ys1 = [[[p['exterior'], *p['holes']] for p in mp] for mp in ys_dict]

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.multi_polygons(xs=xs1,
                ys=ys1, color=['red','green'])
```

This creates two polygons (outer `red` and inner `green`).

The desired behavior is when a user clicks on the `green` one, the `green` would come to front and allow user to explore that one?

Eventually, I will have more nested polygons within the `green` one, so a user can go to multiple depth by selecting a desired polygon. A button to go back to the previous hierarchy would be very useful as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "come to front"? Do you want the axes' ranges to change so that the plot is zoomed in on the green square.

Answer (score 0):

If the answer to my comment to the question is "yes", then here's an example that can get you started. You can reset the zoom by clicking on the "Reset" tool button in the tool panel.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import TapTool, CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

base_xs = [0, 1, 1, 0]
base_ys = [0, 0, 1, 1]


def offset(base, d):
    return [i + d for i in base]


ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(xs=[[[offset(base_xs, dx)]] for dx in base_xs],
                           ys=[[[offset(base_ys, dy)]] for dy in base_ys],
                           color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']))

tt = TapTool(behavior='inspect')
p = figure(tools=[tt, 'reset'])
p.multi_polygons('xs', 'ys', color='color', source=ds)

tt.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(x_range=p.x_range, y_range=p.y_range),
                       code="""\
    const {source} = cb_data;
    const idx = source.inspected.indices[0];
    const {xs, ys} = source.data;
    const poly_xs = xs[idx].flat(2);
    const poly_ys = ys[idx].flat(2);
    x_range.start = Math.min(...poly_xs);
    x_range.end = Math.max(...poly_xs);
    y_range.start = Math.min(...poly_ys);
    y_range.end = Math.max(...poly_ys);
""")

show(p)
```